# Divide each word in txt file and get it

Tags: android, kotlin

I need help, I'm developing app that will read words from txt file in assets and display it to textView, problem is that it displays me all text that is in txt file, but i want to take each word separately.
For example: There is words.txt file in assets and there are words "Android, Kotlin, Java" and i need to display only "Kotlin" word to text, and I don't know how to get it separately, instead of it i get all words.
And i want to randomly display separated text.

There is my code:

```
private fun randomWord() {
        val myOutput: String
        val myInputStream: InputStream

        try {
            myInputStream = assets.open("words.txt")
            val size: Int = myInputStream.available()
            val buffer = ByteArray(size)
            myInputStream.read(buffer)
            myOutput = String(buffer)

            val list = myOutput.toList<String>() //its what i want to do
            binding.textView.text = list.random() //its what i want to do

            //binding.textView.text = myOutput //its that i can use but i dont want it

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I have done, you can view it:

```
private fun randomWord() {
    val myOutput: String
    val myInputStream: InputStream

    try {
        myInputStream = assets.open("words.txt")
        val size: Int = myInputStream.available()
        val buffer = ByteArray(size)
        myInputStream.read(buffer)
        myOutput = String(buffer)

        // Split the string into an array of words.
        val words = myOutput.split(" ")

        // Get a random word from the array.
        val randomWord = words.random()

        // Display the random word in the text view.
        binding.textView.text = randomWord
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are taking the whole file and not splitting it in a List

```
val list = myOutput.toList<String>() //its what i want to do
```

Instead of this, do this

```
val list = myOutput.split(",")
```

this will create a list containing the comma separated strings in your file

Hope this helps

Comment: toList() is not needed as split's return type is List.